# How do I use m_map in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have installed octave on linux ubuntu running as a guest on ubuntu. I am able to plot contours and from http://www2.ocgy.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html#examples. I have also installed m_map and gshhs (both for gmt and for shapefiles, and gmt has been installed). From the instructions on the above site, am not able to link my script (mfile) to the basemap. My script is below

```
#!/usr/bin/octave

data=load('meansr.txt');
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);

obs = data(:,3);
```

% create a regular mesh

```
[xi,yi] = ndgrid(22:0.1:34,-18:0.1:-8);
```

% number of influential points

```
m = 29;
```

% compute the first guess (or background), here we take the mean of all observations

```
mean_obs = mean(obs);
```

% remove the mean

```
f = obs - mean_obs;
```

% background estimation (here the mean)

```
var = 0.01 * ones(size(f));
```

% call optiminterp

```
[fi,vari] = optiminterp2(x,y,f,var,1.5,1.5,m,xi,yi);
```

%put back the mean

```
obsi = fi + mean_obs;

saveas(gcf,'rainzam.pdf'); % This prints to file
```

% insert basemap

```
m_proj('mercator','lat',[-18 -8],'lon',[22 34],'aspect',.8);
m_gshhs_i('patch',[.5 .6 .5]);
m_grid('tickdir','out','yaxislocation','left',...
   'xaxislocation','bottom','xlabeldir','middle','ticklen',.02);
```

These last three lines give errors. I would appreciate advice on how to set up the gshhs_shp directory in relation to m_map, and which paths to change. Currently gshhs_shp directory is in m_map/private.

Comment: "give errors" - which errors?  At any rate, don't put anything in `/private` subdirectories except private functions. If you don't know what a private function is, **don't put anything in /private**.

Comment: Thanks @nkjt and my apologies for posing my post in a very unclear way. What I have so far is to include the following paths in the octave script: ~/m_map, ~/m_map/private, ~/m_map/private/GSHHS_shp/c, ~/m_map/private/GSHHS_shp/l, ~/m_map/private/GSHHS_shp/i, ~/m_map/private/GSHHS_shp/h, ~/m_map/private/GSHHS_shp/f. Am not sure if it is necessary to add all of them, but now my script runs with the only error being "Unknown option: aspect" and the plot is only a grid no contours, no map in it. The contour command contours ok, the three map commends above attempts to bring a map then disappears

Comment: I Removed aspect in my script, no error, but I still get an empty plot. I guess am pretty close to the desired result.

Comment: Still working on my problem, if anyone can assist, with the command "m_plotbndry('mydata.txt','color','r')" I get an error in "m_plotbndry.m" on the line "targetfile = [name,'2pts.mat'];". I wonder what I should put in place of "2pts.mat". mydata.txt is created by my script from the x, y, z data read above. Guidance in m_plotbndry.m is not clear on how to create a .mat file, otherwise I get "error: Could not find mydata.txt2pts.txt,  error: called from: error:   /home/zmumba/m_map/m_plotbndry.m at line 52, column 29" Help will be appreciated