# How to read a map into octave

Tags: gnuplot, octave

This is a follow up to my post three weeks ago here [How do I use m_map in octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438895/how-do-i-use-m-map-in-octave), without really being a nuissance to kind and busy people. My problem is simply how does one overlay a basemap on an octave contour plot. After interpolating my irregularly spaced data (works for both contour lines and filled contours) I plot with the code:

```
contour(xi, yi, obsi, cstart:cstep:cend)
colorbar;

xlabel('Longitude'),ylabel('Latitude')
title('Mean Rain Onset')
saveas(gcf,'rainzam.pdf')
```

And I get
[image: output image]

I have downloaded several map formats: ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip, the apparently obsolete m_map (with associated tbase.Z, gshhg-bin-2.3.2.zip), soa.7z, world-bounds.7z, gshhg-gmt-2.3.2.tar.gz, dcw-gmt-1.1.1.tar.gz.
My question is has anyone used any of these maps in octave or gnuplot, and how to? I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to load those maps in octave, they represent borders or coastlines with two variables (x,y) which you can then add to your plot with

```
hold on
plot(x,y)
```

That's the easy part, the hard part is to load the maps. All of them have different formats, which means it is a completely different story how to load them. For instance, the ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip has a dbf format. Either you convert it first to ascii text and load it easily with the load function of octave or you need the OI package (http://wiki.octave.org/IO_package), which in turn demands java (http://wiki.octave.org/Java_package). I don't think this is the easy way for a newbie, so I suggest to convert the maps individually to text: google for "convert dbf to csv", "convert dbf to text", "convert dbf to ascii", etc... Perhaps some of those maps can be even loaded with excel and then saved as text (csv), the important issue is to convert them to text!

Comment: Thanks @nukimov, that gets me going, I will see how far I will get. Thanks so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw physical coastlines, you may download them from this link

https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

Then, after the drawing of a contour map of your own datas, you may add the coastlines using the following commands:

pkg load mapping

hold on

h = shapedraw ('FileName.shp','r','linewidth',1)